# unable to call Web API service in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I implemented web API service, which includes a POST method. Implemented OWIN Authentication, CORS, Error handling features on it.

I tested in my local box which works well in all browsers: IE, Chrome and Firefox.

The same code I published and pushed into UAT server for testing, service is not working in Chrome and Firefox, but works well in IE.

could you please help me to come out of this issue, appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *not working as expected* What do you mean? does it behavior changed? or you get console error?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, which is spinning in firefox continuously, at some point of time will get Aborted message under Network Traffic tab in firebug. will not return any message in console, but in Chrome i will get _ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE message in console.